# While Loop With Yes/No Input (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

I am building a script to plot smooth and plot values. However, I am having trouble getting the yes/no function to control the while loop.

I am setting the while condition equal to "N" and waiting for the user to say they like the plotting (input of Y) before exiting.

I am getting a "NameError: name 'reply' is not defined."

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

while True:
    reply[0] = 'n'
    def yes_or_no(question):
        reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply[0] == 'y':
            return 1
        if reply[0] == 'n':
            return 0
        else:
            return yes_or_no("Please Enter (y/n) ")

# a bunch of math
# plots for the user

yes_or_no('Do you like the plot')
break
print("done")
```

When I adjusted reply[0] to reply the program hangs (see below)

```
print("started")
while True:
    reply = 'n'
    def yes_or_no(question):
        reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply[0] == 'y':
            return 1
        if reply[0] == 'n':
            return 0
        else:
            return yes_or_no("Please Enter (y/n) ")

yes_or_no('Do you like the plot')
print("done")
```

Comment: You should rarely ever `def` within a loop

Comment: What is the need to define function within the while loop. Also the error is likely to be coming from your statement of `reply[0] = 'n'`. Correct that and see. You should mention full error including line number in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def yes_or_no(question):
    reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
    if reply[0] == 'y':
        return 1
    elif reply[0] == 'n':
        return 0
    else:
        return yes_or_no("Please Enter (y/n) ")

print("started")
while True:
    # DRAW PLOT HERE;
    print("See plot....")
    if(yes_or_no('Do you like the plot')):
        break
print("done")
```

Best to keep function definition separate from loop for clarity. Also, otherwise it will be read in every loop wasting resources.

Output:

```
$ python ynquestion.py 
started
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): n
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): N 
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): NO
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): No
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): no
See plot....
Do you like the plot (y/n): yes
done
$
```

Comment: The recursive design (which, granted, you inherited from the OP's attempt) is unnecessary and brittle. It will cause a stack overflow if they provide invalid input enough times.

Comment: What would be the best method amongst different answers here or on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response ?

Comment: If you are asking for my opinion, I don't have a strong recommendation; but prefer a loop over recursion at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look at some tutorials about "how to code" in general. There are several "misconceptions". However, here is a cleaner version:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def bunch_of_math():
    ...

def plotting():
    ...

# move this into the loop in case you want to calc and plot
# new stuff every iteration
bunch_of_math()
plotting()

print("start")

while True:
    reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
    if reply == 'y':
        break
    elif reply == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print("please select (y/n) only")
        continue

print("done")
```

It is bad style to declare a function inside a loop, especially if you do not need this. Your code would re-create the function at each iteration, which you would only need if you somehow alter your function in each iteration.

`reply[0] = 'n'` means that you want to access the list or array (a container data structure) `reply` with the index `0` and write `'n'` there. You have not initialized such a container. Additionally, you do not need a container at all, because you do not store each user input. You just care for the most recent answer of you user -> a variable is enough.

```
if reply[0] == 'y':
    return 1
if reply[0] == 'n':
    return 0
else:
    return yes_or_no("Please Enter (y/n) ")
```

You have two if conditions after another: Python would check for `== 'y'` and then always check again for `== 'n'`. You need to use `elif` to declare an else-if condition, otherwise you waste resources or ran into unexpected behavior. Additionally, you are never using the return values. The while-loop just exits with a `break` statement, because it is a loop. Thus, your `return` statements are pointless.

Answer (score 1):

```
def yes_or_no(question):
    while True:
        answer = input(question + ' (y/n): ').lower().strip()
        if answer in ('y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'):
            return answer in ('y', 'yes')
        else:
            print('You must answer yes or no.')

yes_or_no('Do you like the plot?')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't intialize an index of an array.

change `reply[0] = 'n'` to `reply = 'n'`

Comment: So - I made the adjustment and it just hangs now print("started")

Comment: @polonius11 It hangs because you define `reply = 'n'`, then a function... and never does the value of `reply` change, or the loop exit

Answer (score 0):

First error - You never defined `reply`, so how do you index that string?

```
while True:
    reply[0] = 'n'  # What is reply??
```

Also `break` is outside the loop, which should be a SyntaxError.

---

Second error - You defined a loop, but never changed the value `reply` in the loop itself. Plus, `yes_or_no()` is called outside of the loop (but it never breaks the loop, only `return`s from the function).

---

You're having some misunderstanding about how functions work. They are separate code blocks, not intended to be nested within your other logic.

```
def yes_or_no(question):
    while True:
        reply = input(question + ' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply.startswith('y'):
            break 

print("started")
yes_or_no('Do you like the plot')
print("done")
```

Or, probably a more readable version

```
def yes_or_no(question):
    return input(question + ' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()

print("started")
question = 'Do you like the plot?'
like_plot = yes_or_no(question).startswith('y')
while not like_plot:
    like_plot = yes_or_no(question).startswith('y')
print("done")
```